# How can I use backdrop-filter on my site?

Tags: html, css

I am currently attempting to increase the width and height of the back-drop filler effect to reflect the image and I am confused on how to do it. The first picture is what I have and the second is what it should look like. I feel it possibly has something to do with increasing the width and height of my nav but when I tried it didn't work out. Could also have something to do with the fact I used absolute with the nav instead of using float but im so confused. Thanks
[image]

[image]

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bellefair&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Space tourism website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="top-logo">
    <img class="logo" src="assets/shared/logo.svg" alt="logo">
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">00</span>Home</a>
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">01</span>Destination</a>
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">02</span>Crew</a>
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">03</span>Technology</a>
  </div>
  <div class="description-container">
    <h5>So, you want to travel to</h5>
    <h1>Space</h1>
    <p>Let’s face it; if you want to go to space, you might as well genuinely go to
    outer space and not hover kind of on the edge of it. Well sit back, and relax
    because we’ll give you a truly out of this world experience!</p>
  </div>
  <button class="btn">Explore</button>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
  background-image: url('../assets/home/background-home-desktop.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
hr {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 9.375rem;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 6.25rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
}
h5 {
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 4.75px;
  font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #D0D6F9;
}
p {
  width: 32%;
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #D0D6F9;
}
.logo {
  margin-right: 70px;
}
.top-logo {
  margin: 53px 0 0 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav > a {
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.nav-number {
  color: white;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 74px;
  right: 230px;
  background: hsl(0 0% 100% / 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
}
.description-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 150px;
}
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  right: 150px;
  width:250px;
height:250px;
border-radius: 50%;
border:none;
background-color:white;
font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
font-size: 2rem;
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try adding padding**

I do all the paddings like this:

```
padding-top: somethingpx;
padding-bottom: somethingpx;
padding-left: somethingpx;
padding-right: somethingpx;
```

But you can do this:

```
padding: 0, 0, 0, 0;
```

but replace the 0 with pixel count.

Comment: Thank you. That helps out a lot but for some reason when I do it I am unable to expand to the entire right side. You know why?

Comment: so in the .nav you have .nav{right: 230px;} I think that could be blocking the right side.

Comment: so try this method